# If I do not have a specific target, is my travelling "targetless"?

Tags: word-choice, word-request, phrase-request, american-english

I'm writing on an english article in the domain of navigation and geographic routing. I have a use case for *targetless* navigation but I'm unsure if the term is the correct choise. I see *targetless* is an existing word in the english language, and it literally means *without target*.

In my specific use case, and in the oppisite to a traditional A-to-B navigation like you use in your car, I'm looking for a term or phrase that descibres the state that

- I'm in a explorative navigation mode
- I'm free to go where I want (as long as I can reach it somehow)
- Describes something scientists call *A-to-N* navigation [1]

Is *targetless navigation* the term I'm looking for?

[1] The *correct* scientific term is the *single source shortest path* (SSSP) problem class in case anyone wants to read up on that matter.

Comment: If you're not trying to reach a destination, you could be said to be **wandering** or **meandering** or **roaming**.  If you're looking for jargon, your question would be better posed elsewhere such as a math forum.  **Target** is not really a synonym for **destination**, and so "targetless" misses the mark.

Comment: Do you have any knowledge whatsoever of these paths, beyond the fact that they exist, before you take them?  Direction? Distance? Attendant conditions?

Comment: *Aimless* is much more idiomatic than *targetless*.

Comment: *Directionless*, perhaps?

Comment: Also: *I have no destination in mind*, therefore I'm wandering, etc.

Comment: "aimless" is used in the phrase "wander aimlessly"

Answer (score 1):

If something that normally takes a target does not have that target set yet, try *untargeted*.

Though this can also refer to something that is not yet targeted by anything as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with something informal, you could use the neologism "[destinationless](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/destinationless)"